# editing app.config in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net

Good day, would anybody be so generous to help me out. I have this project, vb10 with MySql. My connection uses app.config to supply all the connection requirements. Now my problem is how do I write in app.config file if I wanted to edit the connection requirements such us server, user, pass or dbname. I've searched through the net but to no avail. I've got this code:

```
Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
    config.AppSettings.Settings("user").Value = "hello" 'sample new value
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
```

however, it does not change anything to the app.config. Please guys, need help badly.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?532768-NET-2-0-Protected-Configuration-(Encrypting-Config-Files)&highlight=

Comment: Please refrain from using irrelevant tags. This question has nothi9ng to do with MySQL.

Comment: Could it be possible you're looking at the project app.config and this change is actually occurring in the bin folder app.config?